# Compile time option for tracking addref() and release()?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com

Many years ago, I recall using a compile time option for tracing the calls to AddRef() and Release(), used to trace the lifetime of a COM object.

Does this still exist in VS2008?

I am working on some legacy code that has issues with its handling of COM objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you are using ATL, you may output this information by defining [_ATL_DEBUG_INTERFACES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sycfy8ec%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
Otherwise one should manually put the tracing code in the AddRef/Release method implementations or implement an ATL-like wrapper which will implement IUnknown interface with built-in logging functionality.

You may take a look on the implementation of the CComObjectRootBase class.